# Why do my arrays change their value if I am not using them in the loops?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Why am I getting different results from M1 and M2 after running the loops? I am not using them. My goal is to get some arrays based on M1 and M2. I want to replace a column-j from M1 in the column-j of M2 to create the array-j and save it on a list.

```
import numpy 
factores= ['V1','V2','V3','V4']
mean_values = numpy.array([5,5,25,1])

#Uncertainty index 
unc=5 #Measured in percentage
ub2=ub1=mean_values*(1+unc/100)  # 5% up mean
lb2=lb1=mean_values*(1-unc/100)  # 5% below mean
#Dimensions
nd=len(lb1) #determines number of variables considered in sensitivity analysis
np=5     #sample size
x=(numpy.random.rand(np,nd))
one =numpy.ones(np)
sample1 = (1+2*(x-1)*(unc/100)) # The % moved between plus or minus the unc%
M1 = sample1*mean_values # sample 1
y=(numpy.random.rand(np,nd))
sample2 = 1+2*(y-1)*(unc/100) # The % moved between plus or minus the unc%
M2 = (sample2*mean_values) # sample 2
z=(numpy.random.rand(np,nd))
sample3 = 1+2*(z-1)*(unc/100) # The % moved between plus or minus the unc%
M3 = sample3*mean_values # sample 3
lista_N=[]
lista_NTj=[]
NTj=numpy.zeros((np,nd))
matriz_1=M1[:,:]
matriz_2=M2[:,:]

print(M1==M2)
for j in range(nd):
    Nj=numpy.zeros((np,nd))
    Nj=matriz_2
    Nj[:,j]=matriz_2[:,j]
    lista_N.append(Nj) 

for i in range(nd):
    NTj=matriz_1
    NTj[:,i]=matriz_2[:,i]
    lista_NTj.append(NTj)  

print(M1==M2)
```

Comment: In your own words, explain to me step by step why you are expecting M1 and M2 to be equal *before* the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to Stack Overflow.

Indeed you are not using `M1` and `M2` directly, but your `matriz_1` and `matriz_2` essentially bind new names to `M1` and `M2`, in other words, they are still referring to the same underlying matrix.

Thus, whatever changes to `matriz_1` and `matriz_2` will change `M1` and `M2` as well.

To get your intended behaviour (where `M1` and `M2` doesn't change before and after `for` loop), simply add `.copy()` when you are declaring the new arrays `matriz_1` and `matriz_2`:

```
matriz_1=M1[:,:].copy()
matriz_2=M2[:,:].copy()
```

By doing so, you are creating de-linked copies of `matriz_1` and `matriz_2` and whatever changes to them will not affect `M1` and `M2`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!